# Entity Framework Inherit table structure from non abstract class , but create all the fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, xaf

I have several tables declared in the following manner

```
[Table("FileDataQuestions")]
public class QuestionFileData : FileData
{
}
```

FileData is in DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EF

The tables create with a single Id column, but I want them to create with all the fields inherited from FileData

I cannot make FileData abstract because it is not my code. FileData is declared as

```
public class FileData : IFileData, IEmptyCheckable, IObjectSpaceLink, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

The Context class is

```
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.Updating;
using DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EF;
using DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EF.PermissionPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace Exambuddy2.Module.BusinessObjects
{
    [TypesInfoInitializer(typeof(Exambuddy2ContextInitializer))]
    public class Exambuddy2EFCoreDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public Exambuddy2EFCoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<Exambuddy2EFCoreDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ModuleInfo> ModulesInfo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ModelDifference> ModelDifferences { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ModelDifferenceAspect> ModelDifferenceAspects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PermissionPolicyRole> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PermissionPolicyUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FileData> FileData { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ReportDataV2> ReportDataV2 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Source> Sources { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CourseUnit> CourseUnits { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(mb);
            mb.Entity<Topic>().HasOne(b => b.CourseUnit).WithMany(i => i.Topics);
            mb.Entity<Source>().HasOne(b => b.Topic).WithMany(i => i.Sources);
            mb.Entity<Question>().HasOne(b => b.Source).WithMany(i => i.Questions);
            mb.Entity<Answer>().HasOne(b => b.Question).WithMany(i => i.Answers);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried manually mapping the columns? I would shy away from auto-mapping or scaffolding in this case.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the context class. Also, have you tried using `HasBaseType((Type)null)` as mentioned on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance? Based on your current setup of your context class, what tables have been created in the database and how should they look instead?

Comment: Xaf uses `FileData` for all files in a project and its other entities referred to it. If you want to have your own `FileQuestionData`, to me, the only way is to add `properties` and implement the `interfaces` that `FileData` class implemented.

Comment: Apologies, for the late answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I pasted in the code for the context into the question I saw my mistake. The DbSet needs to be created for FileDataQuestions and removed for FileData